# partially correct output in c program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
  int num, rem, no = 0, i = 0;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  do
  {
    rem = num % 10;
    if(rem == 9)
    {
      rem = 0;
    } else {
      rem = rem + 1;
    }
    no = no + (rem * pow(10,i++));
    num = num / 10;
  } while(num != 0);
  printf("new no: %d\n", no);
}
```

this code is to add 1 to every digit of a number entered by user and works fine with 2 digit number but when i enter 3 digit number eg:123, the output is 233 instead of 234

Comment: It is in general a bad idea to use floating point functions with integer arithmetics. Even more as there is absolutely no reason to use `pow` here.

Comment: Indeed (`pow()` is a floating point function) ... and for this particular requirement, I'd consider to operate on the *string* data

Comment: It would be much easier to manipulate the string's characters unless that's arbitrarily forbidden for what I assume is a homework assignment? Try to ask specific questions rather than implying "What am I doing wrong in this code?" as the SO gremlins will down vote and close your questions otherwise ;-)

Comment: i don't understand why is it giving correct output for 2 digit number! and could someone PLEASE post the corrected code so that i may understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code runs fine for me, however it could be a result of floating point rounding as other have suggested.  Rather than using the `pow` function, keep track of the current power of 10 in a separate variable and multiply by 10 on each iteration.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()                        // main should always return int, not void
{
    int num, rem, no=0,i=0,p=1;   // p is the current power of 10
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    do{
        rem=num%10;
        if(rem==9)
        {
            rem=0;
        }else{
            rem=rem+1;
        }
        no+=rem*p;     // multiply by the current power of 10
        p*=10;         // increase the power of 10
        num=num/10;
    }while(num!=0);
    printf("new no: %d\n", no);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now its working fine! thanks :) suggest me some way to understand c programming basics

Comment: err.. "Learn C The Hard Way"? Numerous tutorials out there.

Comment: PS you can always "accept" this answer if it helped you.